# Python - Vectorized difference of dates in two dataframes with millions of rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, vectorization, counting

I have two dataframes:

```
Date                  Variable
2013-04-01 05:00:00     S   
2013-04-01 05:00:00     A   
2013-04-01 05:10:00     S   
2013-04-01 05:20:00     A
2013-04-01 05:25:00     S   
2013-04-01 05:35:00     S
```

And:

```
Date                  Variable
2013-04-01 04:50:00     A   
2013-04-01 05:00:00     A   
2013-04-01 05:05:00     S   
2013-04-01 05:15:00     S
2013-04-01 05:35:00     S   
2013-04-01 05:40:00     S
```

My goal is to count the number of dates on the first dataframe 20 min before and 20min after each date on the second dataframe. So, what I need to do is iterate over all dates on the second dataframe, and count how many dates are in the first dataframe 20min bef and 20min after each specific date. Also, I want to account the number of occurrences of variable A or S, in other words, the Nr_var_20_bef  columns has the number of dates 20min bef with the same variable). Therefore, the output would be something like:

```
Date               Variable   Nr_20_bef   Nr_20_aft  Nr_var_20_bef  Nr_var_20_after  
2013-04-01 04:50:00     A        0            3             0             1
2013-04-01 05:00:00     A        2            4             1             2
2013-04-01 05:05:00     S        2            3             1             2
2013-04-01 05:15:00     S        3            3             2             2
2013-04-01 05:35:00     S        3            1             2             1
2013-04-01 05:40:00     S        3            0             2             0
```

My main problem is that both dataframes have over 1 million rows, and this means that I can not use a for loop or a pandas apply, because they are take way too time consuming with such huge dataframes. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem! I can offer you a partial solution, which will hopefully be enough to get you started.

You should look into pandas `rolling` methods which can take advantage of your DateTime index. Note that, as far as I'm aware, the rolling functions can only look at the previous time period, not a future period. This solution calculates the number of instances of the `bar` column appears in the past 20 minutes according to a set of merged times of `foo` and `bar`, which I believe is what you're asking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Attempting to generate some similar data
np.random.seed(0)
rng = pd.date_range('4/1/2013', periods=1000, freq='5T', name='Date')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable': np.random.choice(['S', 'A'], 1000)}, index=rng)
df1 = df.sample(frac=0.5)
df2 = df.sample(frac=0.5)

merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_foo', '_bar'])

# pandas can't found objects, but can count bools
m = merged.notnull()

# Rolling functions can't count "after", only "before" or "center"
merged['Nr_20_bef'] = m.Variable_bar.rolling('20T').sum()

print(merged.head(10))

                    Variable_foo Variable_bar  Nr_20_bef
# Date
# 2013-04-01 00:05:00            A          NaN        0.0
# 2013-04-01 00:10:00            A          NaN        0.0
# 2013-04-01 00:15:00          NaN            S        1.0
# 2013-04-01 00:20:00            A            A        2.0
# 2013-04-01 00:25:00            A          NaN        2.0
# 2013-04-01 00:40:00          NaN            A        1.0
# 2013-04-01 00:45:00            A            A        2.0
# 2013-04-01 00:50:00          NaN            A        3.0
# 2013-04-01 01:05:00          NaN            A        2.0
# 2013-04-01 01:10:00            S            S        2.0
```

Generating the `Nr_20_bef` column is very fast, ~1 second for 10 million rows on my two year old laptop. If you want to count just "S" characters, for instance, you could instead do `m = merged == 'S'`.